# How to get display keyboard event in android

Tags: android

I have GridView `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with Editboxes, in `LinearLayout` with **fix android:layout_height**.

When I touch editbox, appears keyboard.

**How to change android:layout_height in LinearLayout when keyboard appears and when disappears?**

Comment: hope its working for you..

Comment: Thank you! I try it now. I new in Android, it takes some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the link below hope it may help you

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

http://davidwparker.com/2011/08/30/android-how-to-float-a-row-above-keyboard/

```
private OnSoftKeyboardListener onSoftKeyboardListener;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (onSoftKeyboardListener != null) {
        final int newSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec); 
        final int oldSpec = getMeasuredHeight();
        if (oldSpec > newSpec){
            onSoftKeyboardListener.onShown();
        } else {
            onSoftKeyboardListener.onHidden();
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public final void setOnSoftKeyboardListener(final OnSoftKeyboardListener listener) {
    this.onSoftKeyboardListener = listener;
}

public interface OnSoftKeyboardListener {
    public void onShown();
    public void onHidden();
}
```

Comment: More detailed answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265